# Opening Span For Each Individual TD on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm working on a table that, when you click on any individual td:

1. a span opens and shows you (that td - the first td in the row)
2. When you click on another td, the old span disappears and the new span opens, showing the (new td you've clicked on - the first td in that row).

Here's my code so far:

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">    

      <style>
         td {
            cursor: pointer;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table id="myTable">
         <tr>
            <th>Head Row</th>
            <th>One</th>
            <th>Two</th>
            <th>Three</th>
            <th>Four</th>
            <th>Five</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>Title 1</th>
            <td>10<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
            <td>9<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
            <td>5<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
            <td>3<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
            <td>2<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
            <td>1<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>Title 2</th>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>Title 3</th>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>5</td>
         </tr>


      </table>


      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   window.onload=function() {
        var cells = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('td');
        var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("spanClass");

     
        for (var i=0, n=cells.length;i<n;i++) {
            cells[i].onclick=function() { 
                var firstCell = $(this).parent("tr").find("td:first").text();
                var spans = document.getElementsByClassName('spanClass');
                var didIt = (this.innerText - firstCell);
            for (var j=0, m=spans.length;j<m;j++) {
               spans[j].innerHTML = "";
               spans[j].innerHTML = didIt;
            }
         
        }
        }
    }
</script>

   </body>
</html>
```

Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/jackcode1/pen/ZEpbRQq

When I click on a td, it changes the innerHTML of all the spans, but I just want it to change the innerHTML of the span inside the td you've clicked on. Then, when you click on another span, it doesn't get rid of the old span.

This is creating issues because now the computer thinks there's a new figure inside the td, and returns NaN when you click on a td the second time (and thereafter).

I basically need it to erase the old span content and then immediately after fill a new one, all on the same click

I've tried this a thousand different ways, but I'm not all that good at javascript or jQuery. The code of added is my most recent / I think closest attempt.

If you could help, it would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

PS: I only have the span in one row because I figure once this is solved for one row, it's easy enough to solve it for the other rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you're trying to do in click event. As far as I understood, it will subtract the first cell value from the value in clicked td and show the result. 
You have jQuery code in your loop, so my solution is based on jQuery. You can target the element within parent easily and update the content.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <style>
    td {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Head Row</th>
      <th>One</th>
      <th>Two</th>
      <th>Three</th>
      <th>Four</th>
      <th>Five</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Title 1</th>
      <td>10<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
      <td>9<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
      <td>5<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
      <td>3<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
      <td>2<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
      <td>1<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Title 2</th>
      <td>25<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
      <td>19<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
      <td>16<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
      <td>15<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
      <td>10<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
      <td>2<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      $('#myTable tr td:not(:nth-child(2))').on('click', function() {
        // clear all span
        $('.spanClass').html('');

        // $(this) is your clicked td
        var $tr = $(this).parent('tr');
        var firstCell = $tr.find("td:first").text();
        var didIt = (this.innerText - firstCell);

        $(this).find('.spanClass').html(didIt);
      });
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, Dave. This is really close to what I was asking for. But I was looking for a way to clear or hide the span of another cell when you click on one. So if I click on "9", for instance, it shows -1. That's great. Then I click on "5", and it hides the -1 beside 9 and shows -5 beside the 5. Does that make sense? Any ideas?

Comment: @user1580462 updated my answer. it will clear all span first, perform calculation and print result in one span at a time. This will also support N numbers of rows in your table. Let me know if you have doubt.

Comment: Dave, you're a life saver. I'm going to check this off, anyway. But do you know if there's anyway to exclude the first td from it... this is an additional question, I understand. That's why I'll check it regardless... but that would be an additional huge help. The first td being included is causing problems because then it changes the 10 to 100, which is odd to me. Anyway. Thank you! If you can't/don't want to, all good.

Comment: @user1580462 If you would take the time to look at my updated answer, it does all of this plus skips the first column.

Comment: All I had to do was remove the class from the first cell. Thank you, Ryan.

Comment: @user1580462 What I gave you below uses, `jquery's` `.is` to make sure the cell clicked isn't the first cell which will remain valid even if your first cell has the `className`. If you want to show appreciation, you can upvote my answer.

Comment: @user1580462 updated my answer to exclude first td as needed. just look for updated event binding `$('#myTable tr td:not(:nth-child(2))')`

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your script, you are looping all the spans and replacing their `innerText` with the same value.

As I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do in the logic of the click event, I am posting this now with the hope you will clarify so that I can make any changes that may be necessary.This will at least get you moving in the right direction as it only changes the span of the clicked cell as you asked for.

Please answer these questions as to the logic in the click event handler:

**1.** If I click on the first column, what is to happen? Should it remain unchanged?

```html
<html>
       <head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">    

          <style>
             td {
                cursor: pointer;
             }
          </style>
       </head>
       <body>
          <table id="myTable">
             <tr>
                <th>Head Row</th>
                <th>One</th>
                <th>Two</th>
                <th>Three</th>
                <th>Four</th>
                <th>Five</th>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <th>Title 1</th>
                <td>10<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
                <td>9<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
                <td>5<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
                <td>3<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
                <td>2<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
                <td>1<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <th>Title 2</th>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>16</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>2</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <th>Title 3</th>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>5</td>
             </tr>


          </table>


          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       window.onload=function() {
            var cells = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('td');
            var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("spanClass");

         
            for (var i=0; i < cells.length; i++) {
                cells[i].onclick=function() { 
                    var firstCell = $(this).parent("tr").find("td:first");
                    //If you click anything but the first cell in the row
                    //Change the innerText of the clicked cell
                    //revert the others
                    if(!$(this).is(firstCell)){
                       //clear all the other cells which may have a hyphenated value
                       $(this).closest('tr').find('td').each(function(){
                          $(this).find('.spanClass').text('');
                       });
                       //You already have the cell which is clicked with 'this'
                       $(this).find('.spanClass').text(parseInt($(this).text()) - parseInt($(firstCell).text()));               
                       //$(this).find('.spanClass').text("-" + $(firstCell).text());
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    </script>

       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, this doesn't seem to be working. It's giving me an alert that says "Hi." What I was asking for is closer to what Dave wrote below... + my comment that I added to Dave's answer.

Comment: @user1580462 Try the updated version. It is working as intended.

Comment: Do you know how I can add and remove styles using this? I added background color and padding, but the padding won't disappear so there's just a grey floating box

Comment: @user1580462 What are you talking about? If you want to add and remove styles on an element, just add or remove the class which holds said `css` styling. You can use `jquery` `.addClass(className)` or `.removeClass(className)` or you can use vanilla `javascript` `element.classList.add(className)` or `element.classList.remove(className)`

Comment: Never mind, sorry to bother you. I'll just keep working on it. Thanks for all your help

Comment: @user1580462 See my comment above. I added more information. If you have another question, you should be posting it as a new question with relevant information like you did in this post.